# MagnificPopup, iPhone, popup width wider than viewport

Tags: jquery, viewport, magnific-popup

I'm using magnific popup, and for some reason on some of my pages when I pop up the page in an iFrame the width goes wider than the viewport - this only happens on iOS (my iPhone 5 with latest iOS)!  This doesn't happen in desktop or on Android devices.  The page I'm popping up is responsive, based on Bootstrap 3.  My meta tag is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

and I've tried adding:

```
shrink-to-fit=no
```

But it doesn't have any effect.  I've been trying to fix this for a few days now.  Can anybody help me out please?!?

Comment: **UPDATE**  I've found out what's making it wider than the viewport, but I still can't fix it.  Inside the page being loaded into the iFrame I am binding a slick carousel (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).  Even though it responds gracefully in a desktop browser, this is screwing up the magnific popup width on an iPhone.  Hmmmm.  It's impossible to debug without a Mac/Safari!  Grrrr.

Comment: **UPDATE 2**  So I fixed that issue with some media queries.  But now when I swipe/change the image in my carousel it jumps to the top of the page!  Grrr.  One thing after another.